# How can I disable "confirm form resubmission" messages?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have set a search page and it's working properly, But when i click on back in browser then the problem(mention below) appears, So how can i can i disable this.

```
Confirm Form Resubmission
This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press Reload to resend that data and display this page.
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-is-not-show-confirm-form-resubmission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After processing POST on your page

```
example.com/mypage.php
```

use

```
header('Location: example.com/mypage.php');
```

In this way the post will not be resubmitted and you wont get the alert from browser.

Answer (score -1):

Use the command line option `-disable-prompt-on-repost` for Chrome.