# How to remove Confirm Form Resubmission when redirect using a button with a value to another page

Tags: php, html

Good day, as the title says, how can I do that? What I'm trying to do is that on page 1, I looped all data with each having a button that has value of their specific id, then that button redirects to a common page 2, then I use that id on page 2 to display their whole data, but the problem is that when I refresh, the dialog appears.

I tried using session, but the problem is that when multiple tabs are accessing it.

I haven't really tried PRG, but on my understanding, it is used to send changes to the server using another page, then redirect to the previous page, preventing the dialog when refreshing. I thought of using it, but I don't know how to send the fetched data from page 1.5 to page 2

I'd be really grateful for a solution to this, or if someone can link me to similar problems. Maybe this is a duplicate question, but I just can't find the term for my problem. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control both pages, change the redirect mechanism on page 1 to GET by simply redirecting to a URL with a parameter appended to the address: `target.php?id=42`.

If you control only page 2, you may convert a POST request with an `id` to a GET request:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    header('Location: target.php?id=' . $_POST['id']);
    exit;
}
```

More on GET vs POST [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog), as well as a couple of other answers.

Comment: I have already thought of using GET instead, is it ok to let the user see the ID? that's my concern,that's why I didn't use it

Comment: It depends. In your case I guess it is OK to use get. The link in my answer leads to a discussion on get vs post, check it out.

Comment: I guess I'll go with this approach, thank you for the answer, Cheers!!