# Clear form data after success codeigniter using php not jquery

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

I have a registration form. after success i want to remove `set_value` value and unset all posted value.

**view.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php if(isset($msg)){
     echo $msg;
} ?>
<form action="" method="post">
   <h5>Username</h5>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
   <h5>Password</h5>
   <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" size="50" />
   <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </div>
</form>
```

**Controller function.php**

```
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
      $data->msg='Please fill all field';
      $this->load->view('view',$data);
}else{
     $data->msg='success';
     unset($_POST);
     $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

I try `unset($_POST)` but not worked, also try

```
  public function clear_field_data() {
    $this->_field_data = array();
    return $this;
  }
```

but nothing works. I am using codeigniter 3.1.5..Please help to sort out it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem my self.

**view.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php if(isset($msg)){
 echo $msg;
} ?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <h5>Username</h5>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
  <h5>Password</h5>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" size="50" />
  <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**Controller function.php**

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
  $data->msg='Please fill all field';
  $this->load->view('view',$data);
}else{
 $data->msg='success';
 $this->form_validation->clear_field_data();
 $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

**MY_Form_validation.php**

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function __construct($config)
{
    parent::__construct($config);
}

public function clear_field_data() {
    $_POST = array();
    $this->_field_data = array();
    return $this;
}
}
```

And problem solved in new version codeIgniter.

Comment: your answer works for me but, i have a question, how you could add a new form validation, i could not do like that, i have to put the function inside the CI_Form_validation

Comment: $_POST = array(); this is what i was missing.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh page on success :

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['msg']='Please fill all field';

        }else{
                $data['msg']='success';                
                redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh');                 
        }
        $this->load->view('view',$data);
```

Comment: I tried this `redirect(current_url(), 'refresh');` because i am working in a sub doamin, but it is not showing success msg.

Comment: use session flash for same. `$this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Your message");` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Comment: this is not a great way to solve my problem. because i want to empty `set_value` field. I know i can redirect and  can get empty field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->form_validation->reset_validation();` along with `$_POST = [];`