# PHP ARGON2I password_hash function does not work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have created a PHP file which includes the following code:

```
...
...
$password = password_hash($_GET['password'], PASSWORD_ARGON2I, ['memory_cost' => 2048, 'time_cost' => 4, 'threads' => 3]);
...
...
```

I have tested it on **XAMPP** server on my personal machine, and it works fine. When I transferred the file to my **AWS EC2** server, the password_hash function does not seem to work, I'm using **PHP 7.2.5** on the **AWS EC2**, the **XAMPP** as well. Additional information: my machine is **Windows 10** and the **EC2** is **RedHat**. I have been trying for a whole day to figure this out but no luck. What could be the problem? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Saying things like "does not seem to work" does not help.

Comment: @Mike well, it does not work actually, I tried to do "echo $password = $_GET['password'];' and it works just fine, so the problem must be in the password_hash function, right?

Comment: Is PHP compiled from source? If yes there must be compiled with `--with-password-argon2` also there must be installed packages `argon2 libargon2-0`

Comment: Wait, you're sending passwords with GET? That's a terrible idea. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog/6834275#6834275.

Comment: @Pyton Actually on Ubuntu Argon2 is built in to PHP. In fact, installing the `argon2` package created conflicts with PHP for some reason and I had to remove it to make it work.

Comment: @Abdullah What is the output of `var_dump($password);`

Comment: @Pyton I have installed php using amazon-linux-extras package, and I have just installed libargon2, do I have to remove the php and reinstall it again with --with-password-argon2?

Comment: @Mike thank you Mike for referencing your helpful answer. I also tried var_dump and it returns NULL.

Comment: Remember you can always look at `phpinfo()` or `php -i` to check if extension modules are really linked in. Else check your VMs php.ini or .user.ini etc.

Comment: @mario That is a good tip, I tried php -i and argon2 was not listed with the hashing engines. UPDATE: I tried the same thing on my local machine, argon2 was not listed with the hashing engines as well, yet, it works well on my local machine :/

Comment: Then see `print_r(get_defined_constants());`. Else check out php.ini and associated inclues / edit if feasible / reboot webserver+fastcgi handler. Otherwise summon Amazon support.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php there is no `--with-password-argon2` option. The [installation page for `password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php) indicates that these functions are core PHP and there are [no dependencies on external libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/password.requirements.php) and [nothing to configure at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/password.configuration.php). That's why there will be nothing argon2-related (or even bcrypt/blowfish) listed in `phpinfo()`. If you do figure this out, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: I suspect that your issue is related to the CPU thread count of the machine in which the request is processed.