# How to call a particular section of php code on click of a html button?

Tags: php, html, button

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I am converting mp4 files into mp3 using system command ffmpeg.

```
<?php 

$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir)); 

if (isset($_GET['go'])) {           
foreach ($mp4_files as $f)                          // Line#A
 {

     $parts = pathinfo($f);
     switch ($parts['extension'])
     {
         case 'mp4' :
             $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
             system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);  // Through this command conversion happens. 
     }
 }
}
?>
```

Once the conversion is complete, I am parsing everything into table as shown below:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
       <table>
           <tr>
              <th style="width:8%; text-align:center;" >Action/Status</th>
           </tr>
           <?php
              $mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);
              $mp3_files = array_values($mp3_files);
              foreach ($programs as $key => $program)    { 
                 $file = $mp4_files[$key];     
                 $file2 = $mp3_files[$key];   // file2 is in mp3 folder
              ?>
           <tr>
              <td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="width:90px;" type="button" name="go" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button</td> <!-- Line#B -->   <!-- Go Button -->
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </table>
</form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above that on click of a **Go button (Line#B), foreach loop (Line#A)** is called.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to attach actions to buttons on the client.

Comment: Read a tutorial on AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar I have modified my question. I have pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

The button should be `type="submit"` so that the form will be submitted when you click the form. And either change the form to `method="GET"` or change `$_GET['go']` to `$_POST['go']`. If you want to allow either method, use `$_REQUEST['go']`.

```
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="width:90px;" type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button</td> <!-- Line#B -->   <!-- Go Button -->
```

Comment: `isset($_GET['go'])` will not be true if `name="go"` in html button ?

Comment: Sorry, that part of the answer was wrong. But you need to make the form method match the variable you're using.

Comment: Sorry I am bit confused. Which part of the answer you are saying wrong ? The one which I posted above.

Comment: The part where I said you need to add a `value` attribute to the button.

Comment: If you leave out the value, it will be an empty string, and `isset()` will still be true.

Comment: It means in any event, it will go inside the if condition if we leave out the value ?

Comment: What I want is, it should go inside if condition on click of a button not in any event.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the difference between client-side and server-side code.

Comment: I understand the difference. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: `if ($_GET['Go'])` runs on the server after the form is submitted. So you can't get there without a submission event.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear in my question. This is what I have tried. On click of a button (Line#B), I want the php code 
to be called. Let me know if there is any mistake in it. 

`<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['go-button'])) {
 for each  ($mp4_files as $f) {
 
 }
}
?>

<form action ="" method="POST">

   <td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="width:90px;" type="submit" name="go-button" value="Go"  class="btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button>
</form>`

Comment: It seems right. Not sure why you changed the button name

Comment: I just want to give a different name. I have a quick question. When I refresh the page, it’s going inside the if condition which I don’t want to do. I am wondering what changes I need to do in the php code above so that it goes inside the if condition only on click of a button.

Comment: Is it asking if you want to resubmit the form? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog

Comment: No its not asking me anything. On refresh of a page, it goes inside the if loop and start doing everything.

Comment: I can't see why it would do that, since you're not posting the form so `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` should be `GET`, not `POST`.

Comment: Are you ask me to from POST to GET in if condition ?  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" and isset($_GET['go-button'])) ? Let me know.