# When I refresh the page, the last button I pressed is pressing again. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

For example, clicking a button, random text is written in the textbox. I refresh the page and write different random text in the textbox.

This message appears when refresh: Confirm Form Submission The page you are looking for used the information you entered. Returning to that page may cause your actions to be repeated. Do you want to continue?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to not  display this `confirm form resubmission` warning message?

Comment: yes and the textbox looks empty so don't press the button after refresh

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog

Comment: javascript kodlarıyla düzeldi çok teşekkür ederim :)

Comment: Did you try this :`if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}`

Comment: That helps a lot, Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, I have also added an answer so that it helps to others. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disscussion we had in comment section, you want to avoid confirm form resubmission warning message.

So you can also use this Javascript that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59301873/5519709). It should work for asp.net too:

```
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
```