# 'Confirm Form Resubmission' Error in Dev Environment

Tags: php, forms

I have a piece of `PHP code`, and I'm encountering a `Confirm form resubmission` error when I click the 'Back' button in my browser within my development environment. I've included the relevant code snippet below for reference:

```
    <form method="get" action="">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Auditors</legend>

            <?php

            foreach ($auditors as $id => $auditor) {
                
            } ?>

        </fieldset>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="report_maker" value="Report"/>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Auditors Selected</legend>

            <?php

            foreach ($auditor_types as $type) {
                
            } ?>

        </fieldset>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="reshape" value="Auditors list"/>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Upon clicking the 'Back' button, the code above is executed. During debugging, I noticed that all GET variables are unset, causing it to enter the if block.

**Problem Statement:** After clicking 'Back' button, I received a `Confirm form resubmission` error. I'm looking for guidance on how to modify the code to resolve this issue.

**Expected Result:** When clicking `Back` button, the page should display the following headings and content inside the form:

Headings:

1. Title: Hello World
2. Heading: Hello World Report
3. Fieldset: Auditors

   - Legend: Auditors
   - (Content generated by PHP loop, as shown in the code)
4. Fieldset: Auditors Selected

   - Legend: Auditors Selected
   - (Content generated by PHP loop, as shown in the code)

Form Content:

The form should include all the inputs and elements as defined in the code snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the back button does not reload the page, it resends the previous request. So, if the previous request was a form submission, it will try to resubmit the form. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is to redirect the user on other page upon form submission.

Or you can display a confirmation page on a new tab.

Don't rely on back button because it will resubmit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the warning message of your browser asking for confirmation to re-send the form request is relevant to your code.

I write that because the `<form>` you have in your question is of `method="get"` and from what I have in mind the browser displays such messages only for the `POST` method. Additionally your vague formulation suggests that going back is before the form in question.

What you have as *problem statement* actually is none, it is only the description which action/button triggers the back button re-submitting warning display asking for configuration feature, which is not an issue but a feature of the browsers user interface. Therefore there is no issue to resolve or at least not what you clarify in your expectations that follow would allow to solve.

To prevent seeing the interactive confirmation dialog the browsers' user needs to confirm, the user needs to configure the browser to not display the message. However this setting will only prevent the message not change the browser navigation behaviour. Effectively the browsers' dialog you're concerned about allows the user to cancel the navigation (of the back button).

This is a safety feature, to prevent re-submission of a form, for example initiating two expensive form submission transactions while only one was intended. Not every webapp is very clever with form handling... .

Nevertheless the user stays in control and browsers offer to override the (sane) defaults, allowing the user to configure her own browser to their liking (or switch to a different browser if their current preferred vendor fails to provide such basic functionality).

The issue you describe is therefore likely unrelated to that dialog.

To display the various data inside the page including form fields, navigate to the appropriate page with the get variables in the query-info part of the URL. The PHP script for that page will then show the values as you expect.

If the overall scenario is because a POST request resulted in the page with the form of method GET, ensure that the POST request URL also has these "GET variables" already in the query component in its URI.

Here is a schema of the relevant URL parts from RFC 3986 and alike, shortened for this answer, effectively you're interested in the query component:

```
    http://example.com/foo/bar?key=value
    \__/   \_________/ \_____/ \_______/
    name   hostname     path     query
```

more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

If you do not provide the correct query, the title and form fields will be always displayed empty. It should not be unexpected then as the URL/URI clearly identifies the query of the hypertext resource as such.

If you need to have it otherwise (mind client side caching then!) you can add more control on the server-side by using session management, PHP has this out of the box.