# Start session after destroy php

Tags: php, session, echo, logout, destroy

I have a logout file for my web application. I would like to create a session after the logout so that I can echo a logout success message. My logout code works but I am unable to create a new session after destroying the previous one.

What is the best way to do this, see code:

```
//LOGOUT.PHP
session_start(); 

//// unset all $_SESSION variables
session_regenerate_id();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

$_SESSION['logoutsuccess'] = 'You have successfully logged out.';
header("Location: /login/");
exit;


//LOGIN.PHP (ECHO SUCCESS MESSAGE)

if(isset($_SESSION['logoutsuccess']))
{
echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['logoutsuccess'].'</div>'; 
unset($_SESSION['logoutsuccess']);
}
```

I would like to avoid passing variables in the url if possible.

Comment: Is there any good reason for doing the redirect? Why can't you show the success status on the logout page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to store it as a session variable, you could check the referer and check for /logout/

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'logout')  !== false) {
  echo 'You have successfully logged out.';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Call `session_start()` again after `session_destroy()`?

Comment: This is the best approach for your specific question, but I still don't see why you don't just show the message on the LOGOUT.PHP page.

Comment: @WatermarkStudios I'm doing the same thing.. he's possibly doing the redirect to avoid form resubmission on refresh... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php

Answer (score 6):

Just start a new session:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSION['food'] = 'pizza';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
session_id($session_id_to_destroy);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, what it does, why, how... something, also note that OP is from 2011