# double saving occures when refresh the page using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php script and i give all data and save data stored on my mysql database.But after that if refresh the page the same data will again stored in database.How i can avoid this.Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php)

Comment: After user submits, you have to navigate them away for the form page.

Comment: With out your code It cant be predict as what is happening

Answer (score 1):

1. Use header and redirect the page.

   `header("Location:your_page.php");` You can redirect to same page or different page.
2. Unset $_POST after inserting it to Database.

   `unset($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are resending the form data on page refresh. If once you save the form data don't render the same form again to the view. You must prevent it by checking if data is saved. Also you can redirect the user from the form view if saving is success.