# submit form only on button click not on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Below is my code, and is working fine.. The only problem is that when I refresh the page , It execute the success query.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Purchase" id="btn" name="link_credits">
</form>

if(isset($_REQUEST['link_credits'])) 
{
echo "success";
//some codes here with sql statements
}
Else 
{ 
echo " Please try Again tomorrow"; 
}

?>
```

Problem:

I don't want to run the query with page refresh, it should run the code only at button click.

Comment: which, is normal. what's the question?

Comment: edited. sorry for being so quick in posting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the line unset($_REQUEST['link_credits']); in success loop

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['link_credits'])) 
    {
    echo "success";
    //some codes here with sql statements

    if($success){
    $_SESSION['msg']="Data Added successfully";
    }
    else{
    $_SESSION['msg']="Data Not Added successfully.Please Check";
    }
    unset($_REQUEST['link_credits']);
    header("Location:--somepage.php--");    
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo " Please try Again tomorrow"; 
    }
```

Then you can show the `$_SESSION['msg']` value in --somepage.php-- and after showing use `unset($_SESSION['msg']);`

Comment: this works... but the problem is it does not display success message.
can i set timer before it redirects to next page

Comment: To     show the error or success message you need to use Session and then unset the session in next page;

Comment: works well. except message not being displayed. i am redireting it to the same page, after uset... and trying to display echo "" after header(), but it does not work.. rest is ok..

Answer (score 1):

Your browser *should* be warning you that a page refresh will re-submit the form.  So, you are clicking a button even when you refresh the page, or you are using a broken browser.

All that being said, here are some possible solutions:

1. Cookie the browser during the "success" phrase, and only allow the success condition to run if the cookie is not set/present.
2. Learn about "Redirect after POST", which is what you *should* be doing here.  Essentially, you perform the success action, set flags as apropos, and forward the browser (via PHP's header()) to a page that says, "OK, it worked!".

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to.

```
if(isset($_POST['link_credits'])){
echo "success";
//some codes here with sql statements
}
else 
{ 
echo " Please try Again tomorrow"; 
}
```

Comment: it run please try again even, I press the the button.. There are more than 5 forms with different names. i hope this should not impact the code

Comment: You can use any number of buttons, but each button should have unique names and use if conditions accordingly `if(isset($_POST['button_name']))`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are submitting the form to the same page with the method post, so when you refresh the page it novamento sent another request post.

Solution:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['link_credits'])) {
  echo "success";
  $_REQUEST['link_credits'] = null;
} else {
  echo " Please try Again tomorrow"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of simply on refresh it will submit your request again.

So the idea to solve this issue by cure its root of cause.

I mean we can set up one session variable inside the form and check it when update.

```
if($_SESSION["csrf_token"] == $_POST['csrf_token'] )
{
// submit data  
}

//inside from 

$_SESSION["csrf_token"] = md5(rand(0,10000000)).time(); 

<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value=" 
htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["csrf_token"]);">
```