# How to prevent re-submit form by reloading page without redirection

Tags: forms, post, submit, reload

I have a probleme with submit form (booking)  it re-submit on page reload

this is code of conditions to post :

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty( $_POST['action'] )
 && $_POST['action'] == "new_post" ){ 
       if(!empty($_POST['start']) || !empty($_POST['end'])){
        // submit and send email}  
}
```

after submit it show thank message and details of booking ( else it shows errors and the form)  but if user reload page it re-submit a post again in database!

can someone give me an idea , i tried to unset `$_POST['end']` and `$_POST['end']` but nothing works

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

There is something called Post Redirect Get pattern. You can use this pattern to avoid post request resubmission on reload. After post request do a redirect rather than directly sending success message

for reference

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php#_=_)

Comment: its not a basic success message but booking confirmation and its details and offer to user to download the confirmation page in pdf.