# How to prevent double submission after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 'contact us' html form and I'm giving gift for each member that click submit.
I want to make sure that a user doesn't submit twice (with different name and email). 
I can disable the button after click, but what will be the best solution to prevent submit after page refresh?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code? The guessing game is too broad for SO

Comment: Best solution? Serverside language and a database.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking for suggestions. It's for posting code that you have written, but doesn't work.

Comment: This is an "anti-forgery token".  Add a hidden field to your form with a randomly generated number.  If you see that number in multiple submissions, you know its a double-submit.  If you also include a cookie token, this can be used to prevent CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Is to directly redirect from your `POST` to a `GET` request or page. if he/she refreshed it will refresh the other page. this is named Redirect After Post and you can read more about it [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) and in [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

An Example can be found [here](http://webdevelopmentscripts.com/26-prevent-submit-on-page-refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you can do and you should do.

1. First disable the `Submit` button as soon as your client submits the form 
      with valid information in it. So that he/she accidently doesn't send 
      duplicate information in the form.
2. Second, which is more important. Is before you save this information in 
      your database whatever that is MySQL, MongoDB or etc. You perform a query
      that checks whether the information provided by the user exists in your db 
      already or not. If not then proceed as you do but if it does you can do 
      error handling on the use case scenario as per your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656609/1066234