# What prompts Confirm Form Resubmission?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two `<input type ="submit">` with `formaction` inside a `<form method="post" action="">` and these suckers prompt the `Confirm Form Resubmission` on refresh:

```
<form method = "post" action="">
  <input class = "button" type="submit" name="dhcp" value="DHCP IP" title="Redirect to DHCP IP Config page" formaction="/dhcp_ip.php">
  <input class = "button" type="submit" name="static" value="Static IP" title="Redirect to Static IP Config page" formaction="/static_ip.php">
</form>
```

I was led to believe that `<form method="post">` or any `POST` method prompts `Confirm Form Resubmission` so I have eliminated the form and replaced it with two `button` elements:

```
<button class="button" onclick="goDHCP()">DHCP IP</button>
<button class="button" onclick="goStatic()">Static IP</button>
<script>
    function goDHCP() {
        window.location.replace("/dhcp_ip.php");
    }
    function goStatic() {
        window.location.replace("/static_ip.php");
    }
</script>
```

But this also prompts `Confirm Form Resubmission` on refresh.

What element prompts it ? And how can I not prompt it ? Because I also have some `<input type="text">`, on other pages, which do not prompt `Confirm Form Resubmission` on refresh, unless the user starts typing something in them.

Comment: You cannot have 2 submit inside one form.

Comment: Do you have only those 2 buttons in the form ?

Comment: @BhavikKalariya - yes, you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed (F5 / CTRL+R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's about two buttons. I don't think I need to use `Post/Redirect/Get` pattern for two buttons.

Comment: Why have buttons and not just a styled `a`-tag (which does exactly what you're trying to do using buttons and js)?

Comment: Because the style is already made. I have the same css class for every button on my webpages. Wouldn't it be strange to style each and every button separately ?

Answer (score 1):

`Confirm Form Resubmission` means that you are trying to refresh a page where data was sent to.
If you don't want to have this popup, click the URL bar and hit enter to revisit the same page without sending data.

As to your form...

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo '
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location.replace("/'.$_POST['direction'].'.php");
      </script>
   ';
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
   <select name="direction">
      <option value="dhcp_ip">Redirect to DHCP IP Config page</option>
      <option value="static_ip">Redirect to the Static IP Config page</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
     Visit page
   </button>
</form>
```

If you need any explanations, please let me know.