# Table truncated on every refresh

Tags: php, sql, database, truncate

I have added a button to my HTML page so that I may truncate my SQL database table whenever the user needs to.

However every time I refresh the page now the table gets truncated, without me pressing the button.

Anyone know the way around this?

Button submit code:

```
<form method="post" action="eDBase.php">
<input name="truncate_But" type="submit" value=" Truncate Table " />
</form>
```

Button truncate code:

```
if(isset($_POST['truncate_But']))
{
    mysqli_query($conn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE `clientinfo`');
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: If you refresh the page after submitting the form, you'll get a box asking if you want to resubmit the form -- you probably clicked yes. If you load the page, it will not do truncate anything, at least not without clicking the button (with your current code).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed (F5 / CTRL+R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr)

Comment: Not quite sure how to follow the PRG method, is there no way for the truncate method to be sent only once.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="post" action="eDBase.php">
<input name="truncate_But" type="submit" value="Truncate Table" />
</form>

 if(isset($_POST['truncate_But']) && $_POST['truncate_But'] == "Truncate Table")
 {
    mysqli_query($conn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE `clientinfo`');
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
 }
```

Comment: No every time I refresh the table table is still truncating.

Comment: you should try with <input name="truncate_But" type="submit" value="Truncate Table" /> instead of  <input name="truncate_But" type="submit" value=" Truncate Table " />

Comment: It's okay Iw worked it out myself. I redirected user to another php file page, did the truncating, then redirect back to my original php page after a 5 second wait. Solves the issue