# How can I unset submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-workbench

I am making a page that adds information to a table in the database but everytime I refresh the page, it adds it again. I have tried `header('Location: index.php'); exit();` but it errors out saying "localhost tried to redirect you too many times."

This is my code

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="nume" required>
      <input type="text" name="prenume" placeholder="prenume" required>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Adauga in baza de date">
      <br>
    </form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
      </tr>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['sub']))
      {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
        $nume = $_POST['nume'];
        $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
        $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume)values(:nume,:prenume)";
        $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
        $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume));
        $_POST = array();
      }
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
      $query = "select * from liamed.users";
      $d = $pdo->query($query);
      foreach ($d as $data){

    ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['id'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['nume'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['prenume'];?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
<?php }
  unset($_POST['sub']);
?>
</html>
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: Maybe this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr

Comment: If you refresh the page after submitting it you actually resubmitting it resulting with an extra entry to your table.