# Submit form one time after page load via Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to submit the cart request-quote form after page load?
Below code is worked fine -

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['updated'])) { ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery("#yith-ywraq-form").submit();
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

But avoid submitting forms, again and again, I reload to this action
site.com/request-quote/?updated=data

But if someone refreshes the same page site.com/request-quote/?updated=data
then I have no option to submit the form again on page load.

do you have a solution for this problem?

My requirement is I want to submit the cart request-quote form 1 time after page load?

Answer (score 1):

You can move `$_GET['updated']` to `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, then you don't need to reload the page to `?updated=data` page anymore.

- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) will save `updated` value even when the browser is closed and reopened.
- [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) will save `updated` value but it will be cleared if the browser is closed.

That depends on you to choose which one. So I make a demo with `sessionStorage` which I prefer because when the user closes the browser, it will clear the `updated` value, maybe the next user in that device is another (public device). I also remove the check `if(!isset($_GET['updated']))` condition.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('updated')) {
      jQuery("#yith-ywraq-form").submit();
      sessionStorage.setItem('updated', true);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Update:** add live demo https://codepen.io/tuandaodev/pen/jOwvrRg?editors=1111

Comment: that code is not working.

Comment: @thecodedeveloper.com I added a real demo. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use localStorage for this.
Take a flag in set some initial value of it.
When the form submits update it's value.
By checking the same you can avoid getting submit.

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['updated'])) { ?>
    <script>
        if(!localStorage.getItem('isFormAlreadySubmit')){
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                jQuery("#yith-ywraq-form").submit();
                localStorage.setItem('isFormAlreadySubmit', true);
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side session variable to check (duplicate)
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr)